# In Java, how do I get the difference in seconds between 2 dates?

Tags: java, datetime, date

The Java class library has a class named DateTime. DateTime has this method:

```
int daysBetween(DateTime other)
```

which returns the number of days between this and the parameter.
It doesn't have a method

```
int secondsBetween(DateTime other)
```

which I happen to need.
Is there a class which is similar to DateTime but has such a method?

Comment: This might help :http://www.xmission.com/~goodhill/dates/deltaDates.html

Comment: If you're on java 8 you have a few more options see https://stackoverflow.com/q/25747499/32453

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Not familiar with DateTime...

If you have two Dates you can call getTime on them to get millseconds, get the diff and divide by 1000. For example

```
Date d1 = ...;
Date d2 = ...;
long seconds = (d2.getTime()-d1.getTime())/1000;
```

If you have Calendar objects you can call

```
c.getTimeInMillis()
```

and do the same

Comment: When time difference is not so high - int seconds = (int) ((d2.getTime()-d1.getTime())/1000);

Comment: @sebrock - fixed to show type as long - casting to int will work for smaller amounts

Comment: @Xdg I was designing an interface lately and came across the same 'problem', but `Integer.MAX_VALUE` can represent almost 70 years in seconds. That was sufficient for me.

Comment: I am looking for answer using LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 36):

I should like to provide the modern answer. The other answers were fine when this question was asked, but time moves on. Today I recommend you use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

```
    ZonedDateTime aDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 12, 8, 19, 25, 48, 991000000, ZoneId.of("Europe/Sarajevo"));
    ZonedDateTime otherDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 12, 8, 20, 10, 38, 238000000, ZoneId.of("Europe/Sarajevo"));

    long diff = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(aDateTime, otherDateTime);
    System.out.println("Difference: " + diff + " seconds");
```

This prints:

```
Difference: 2689 seconds
```

`ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between()` works with two `ZonedDateTime` objects or two `OffsetDateTime`s, two `LocalDateTime`s, etc.

If you need anything else than just the seconds, you should consider using the `Duration` class:

```
    Duration dur = Duration.between(aDateTime, otherDateTime);
    System.out.println("Duration: " + dur);
    System.out.println("Difference: " + dur.getSeconds() + " seconds");
```

This prints:

```
Duration: PT44M49.247S
Difference: 2689 seconds
```

The former of the two lines prints the duration in ISO 8601 format, the output means a duration of 44 minutes and 49.247 seconds.

### Why java.time?

The `Date` class used in several of the other answers is now long outdated. Joda-Time also used in a couple (and possibly in the question) is now in maintenance mode, no major enhancements are planned, and the developers officially recommend migrating to `java.time`, also known as JSR-310.

### Question: Can I use the modern API with my Java version?

If using at least Java **6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).
- On Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP, and there’s a thorough explanation in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Very underrated answer. Jodatime's calculations here are a little messy. However `ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(oldDate.toInstant(), newDate.toInstant())` is rather easy to remember.

Answer (score 10):

You should do

```
org.joda.time.Seconds.secondBetween(date1, date2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for contributing. This would be a stronger post if you explained why this is the way to go.

Comment: Also it is Seconds.secondsBetween(date1, date2)

Comment: @divonas makes no difference. His notation explicitly refers to joda

Comment: The correct method name is 'second**s**Between'. That said this is the cleanest way I found with org.joda.time.DateTime.

Comment: If you want the results as an int you should call getSeconds() on the result.`Seconds.secondsBetween(start, end).getSeconds()`

Comment: I think there's a java 8 way of doing this now that doesn't require jodatime. I'm on the lookout for it.

Answer (score 7):

That should do it:

```
Date a = ...;
Date b = ...;

Math.abs(a.getTime()-b.getTime())/1000;
```

Here the relevant documentation: [Date.getTime()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()). Be aware that this will only work for dates after January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: Hmm, why would this only work for dates after Jan 1, 1970? Before that the values are negative, but arithmetic works on negative numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils` to make it cleaner:

```
(firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND
```

Comment: `DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_SECOND` +1 for that

Answer (score 5):

There is no such class as `DateTime` in the standard Java SE API. Although there is one in joda-time, even that does not have a `daysBetween` method.

Using the standard Java API, the easiest way to get seconds between two `java.util.Date` objects would be to subtract their timestamps and divide by 1000:

```
int secondsBetween = (date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not recommended to use `java.util.Date` or `System.currentTimeMillis()` to measure elapsed times. These dates are not guaranteed to be monotonic and will changes occur when the system clock is modified (eg when corrected from server). In probability this will happen rarely, but why not code a better solution rather than worrying about possibly negative or very large changes?

Instead I would recommend using [`System.nanoTime()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()).

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
long t2 = System.nanoTime();

long elapsedTimeInSeconds = (t2 - t1) / 1000000000;
```

**EDIT**

For more information about monoticity see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937619/how-can-i-measure-time-in-java-not-susceptible-to-system-clock-changes/1939447#1939447) to a related question I asked, where possible nanoTime uses a monotonic clock. I have tested but only using Windows XP, Java 1.6 and modifying the clock whereby `nanoTime` was monotonic and `currentTimeMillis` wasn't.

Also from [Java's Real time doc's](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/faq.jsp#50):

> Q: 50. Is the time returned via the
>   real-time clock of better resolution
>   than that returned by
>   System.nanoTime()?
>
> The real-time clock and
>   System.nanoTime() are both based on
>   the same system call and thus the same
>   clock.
>
> With Java RTS, all time-based APIs
>   (for example, Timers, Periodic
>   Threads, Deadline Monitoring, and so
>   forth) are based on the
>   high-resolution timer. And, together
>   with real-time priorities, they can
>   ensure that the appropriate code will
>   be executed at the right time for
>   real-time constraints. In contrast,
>   ordinary Java SE APIs offer just a few
>   methods capable of handling
>   high-resolution times, with no
>   guarantee of execution at a given
>   time. **Using System.nanoTime() between
>   various points in the code to perform
>   elapsed time measurements should
>   always be accurate.**

Comment: Hmm, interesting post. What makes you say that nanoTime is not subject to clock updates? I don't see anything in the Java documentation about this. I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm must wondering if you have a reference or have performed experiments to back this up.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Joda (which may be coming as jsr 310 in JDK 7, separate open source api until then) then there is a Seconds class with a secondsBetween method.

Here's the javadoc link: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Seconds.html#secondsBetween(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)

Answer (score 1):

For java 8+ you can use

`ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(temporal1,temporal2)`

Comment: Yes. That’s what I already recommend in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47720172/5772882).

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't notice that

Comment: It may be easier to spot in a short answer like yours than in a long one like mine. I suggest we both let our answers stand.

Answer (score 0):

Which class ? Do you mean the Joda [DateTime](http://www.jdocs.com/jodatime/1.2.1/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class ? If so, you can simply call `getMillis()` on each, and perform the appropriate subtraction/scaling.

I would recommend Joda for date/time work, btw, due to it's useful and intuitive API, and its thread-safety for formatting/parsing options.

Comment: That's not a standard library (neither is Joda), nor is it particularly well-know (unlike Joda)

Answer (score 0):

Just a pointer:
If you're calculating the difference between two java.util.Date the approach of subtracting both dates and dividing it by 1000 is reasonable, but take special care if you get your java.util.Date reference from a Calendar object.
If you do so, you need to take account of daylight savings of your TimeZone since one of the dates you're using might take place on a DST period.

That is explained on Prasoon's link, I recommend taking some time to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
private Long secondsBetween(Date first, Date second){
    return (second.getTime() - first.getTime())/1000;
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Comment: Its clear that you need to send two Dates, i mean,   Date initialDate = new Date()   and Date finalDate = new Date()    so if you send initialDate and finalDate you can get the difference in secods...   both of them will be "convertt" to Long with the method getTIme and finally you will get the difference divided by 1000 to get the seconds...    great answer by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Use time unit class.

```
long timeDifferentInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(currentDate.getTime()) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(previousDate.getTime());
```