# How to find out seconds between two dates in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, how do I get the difference in seconds between 2 dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970239/in-java-how-do-i-get-the-difference-in-seconds-between-2-dates)

Hi i have two dates as follows

1970-01-01 and 
2011-08-01 which are in yyyy-mm-dd format.

How to find out the seconds difference between two above dates.

Comment: are you only get the seconds from the epoch to the current data every time? If so you can just call `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000`

Answer (score 3):

Create two `java.util.Date` objects (yes, the deprecated ones).

Use the `getTime()` method on each object to get milliseconds from the epoch.

Subtract the smaller time from the larger time, and then convert to seconds by dividing by one thousand.

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert both to dates using `SimpleDateFormat`.
2. Get the difference between them by calling `getTime()` and subtracting one from the other.
3. Divide the number by 1000 to get seconds.