# Java calculating time with timestamps

Tags: java, date, calendar, timestamp

Im trying to calculate the time difference between 2 Timestamps, this is the code:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.util.Date now = calendar.getTime();
        Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(now.getTime());
        System.out.println("Current\n"+currentTimestamp);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = dateFormat.parse("28/02/2015");
        Timestamp timestampBefore = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        System.out.println("Before\n"+timestampBefore);

        Timestamp calculated = new Timestamp(currentTimestamp.getTime() - timestampBefore.getTime());
        System.out.println("Calculated\n"+calculated);
```

Output:

```
Current
2015-02-28 12:12:40.975
Before
2015-02-28 00:00:00.0
Calculated
1970-01-01 13:12:40.975
```

1. I can understand why it returns `1970-01-01` but why does it return `13:12:40.975` ,1 hour more?
2. How to calculate the difference between 2 dates so the output is like this (based on this example):
   Years:0, Months:0, Days:0, Hours:12, Minutes:12, Seconds:40 ?

**Update**: for java below 1.8 check out http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html
and for java 1.8 see answer.

**Similar solution here:** [Java 8: Calculate difference between two LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime)

Comment: The difference between two timestamps is not a timestamp, but a duration. It is useless to convert it to a date/time.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the timezone. can you print calculated time with  timezone?

Comment: @Jens the timezone shouldnt be a problem, its the exact hour (12:12:40.975) as my pc hour.

Comment: Basically, the solution here is to use Joda Time or `java.time`. Do *not* treat a duration as a date/time.

Comment: @JonSkeet   Damn, really appreciate a Google’s engineer spending time on such questions :)

Comment: I disagree with your "Update" statement. Joda-Time works perfectly well in Java 8. While java.time was inspired by Joda-Time, it is re-architected. Both Joda-Time and java-time each have their strengths and weaknesses including features the other lacks. You can use both in a project as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) A timestamp is a point in time. If you calculate the difference between two timestamps, the result is not a timestamp (point in time), but a duration. So it is nonsense to convert the difference to a timestamp, hence it is useless to discuss the reason why the result is strange.

(2) You should probably use the new [Java 8 time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/package-summary.html) (if you are able to use Java 8):

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
LocalTime previous = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 0);
Duration duration = Duration.between(previous, now);

System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(previous);
System.out.println(duration);
```

Note that this just calculates the duration between two times of a day (hour-minute-second). If your want to include date information, use `LocalDateTime` instead:

```
LocalDateTime nextFirework = LocalDate.now()
                             .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextYear())
                             .atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

// duration (in seconds and nanos)
Duration duration = Duration.between(now, nextFirework);
// duration in total hours
long hours = now.until(nextFirework, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
// equals to: duration.toHours();
```

If you want to have 'normalized' duration in years/months/days/hours/seconds, there is suprisingly no direct support. You could convert the duration to days, hours, minutes and seconds by yourself:

```
long d = duration.toDays();
long h = duration.toHours() - 24 * d;
long m = duration.toMinutes() - 60 * duration.toHours();
long s = duration.getSeconds() - 60 * duration.toMinutes();
System.out.println(d + "d " + h + "h " + m + "m " + s + "s ");
```

But note that you will have difficulties converting the days into months and years, as there is no unique number of days per month and a year can be a leap year with 366 days. For that, you can use `Period`, as in opposite to `Duration`, this class is associated with a timeline. Unfortunately, `Period` does only support dates, but no times:

```
// period in years/months/days (ignoring time information)
Period p = Period.between(now.toLocalDate(), nextFirework.toLocalDate());
System.out.println(p); // or use p.getYears(), p.getMonths(), p.getDays()
```

So probably you could combine both approaches - first, compute the `Period` from the dates and then the `Duration` using the times. Note that the duration can be negative, so you'll have to take care of that in case of:

```
Duration dur = Duration.between(start.toLocalTime(), end.toLocalTime());
LocalDate e = end.toLocalDate();
if (dur.isNegative()) {
    dur = dur.plusDays(1);
    e = e.minusDays(1);
}
Period per = Period.between(start.toLocalDate(), e);
System.out.println(per.toString() + ", " + dur.toString());
```

Comment: how can i get ONLY hour of duration? Is there anything similar to duration.getHour()?

Comment: That's ambiguous: Do you want to have the total duration in hours, or just the hour part of a normalized duration in the form years+months+days+hours+minutes+seconds?

Comment: id like the output to be like this: Years:0, Months:0, Days:0, Hours:12, Minutes:12, Seconds:40  , everything "normalized". I tought of getting the duration and splitting it into small strings but i bet theres a better way of doing it.

Comment: See my edit. It is not that trivial as months (28-31 days) and years (365-366 days) have no unique definition. And of course daylight saving adds more complexity...

Comment: got it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime ,this is what i wanted, now im not sure if it manages to get the leaps correclty.

Comment: Joda-Time does support defining a span of time as hours, days, and such. See the [`Period`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class. By the way, [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) [defines](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) a String format for hours days and such: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates date portion from time portion. So `P3DT2H` means "three days and two hours". Joda-Time generates and parses such strings by default.

Comment: @Alpha2k The SO answer you mention does not support the case where the time of the second date-time value is less than the time of the first date-time value; It will return a negative time in this case. (e.g. today at 3 pm until tomorrow 2 pm will return "1 day -1 hour" instead of "23 hours")