# How long has it been from MySQL row Timestamp?

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

So Basically I have a table in MySql DB, which when a user upload something it register the item with an automated timestamp. Now in my client side I need to show the user how long has it been from item upload. Similar like youtube comments or Something like:

Upload Time | MySql TimeStamp: `2017-03-24 22:13:03` Current time: `2017-03-24 22:14:03` The result for has to be `1 hour`.

I would really appreciate if someone tell how to do it automatically.
I'm using Java, MySql which ever is easy.

Java:

```
String date = null,item="auniqueid";
String query = "Select date from table where item=?";
try {
        DBConnect Database = new DBConnect();
        Connection con = Database.getcon();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, item);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            date=rs.getString(1);
        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Regards

Comment: @Dev.Joel See the update

Comment: @Dev.Joel `INSERT INTO table (USERID, VIDEOID) VALUES (?,?);` TimeStamp is autogenerated

Answer (score 0):

In java
`date.getTime()` returns milliseconds. Convert your both current and stored time stamp and calculate the difference.

Reference [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime())

TO calculate the duration, best way to convert both time stamp into seconds.

JAVA 8 (Easy)
You can use the new Java 8 time API (if you are able to use Java 8):

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
LocalTime previous = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 0);
Duration duration = Duration.between(previous, now);

System.out.println(now);
System.out.println(previous);
System.out.println(duration);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781087/java-calculating-time-with-timestamps)