# how can i format the java.sql.Date to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: java, jsp, date, sqldatetime

my code is

```
final long MILLIS_IN_A_DAY = 1000*60*60*24;
Date yesterdaydate= new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime() - MILLIS_IN_A_DAY);
out.println(yesterdaydate);
```

the output am getting is in format yyyy/mm/dd..how can i get it in MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: iQué horror!  Please don't *ever* write code like this in production software!  As far as "date differences" in Java, please consider using [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html), or [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime.  As far as "date formatting", just use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Please don't ever assume there are exactly 24 hours in a day.  Most places have a 25 hour day once per year, and a 23 hour day once per year.

Comment: @paulsm4 [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is not applicable if using Java 8 or Joda-Time. They each have their own formatters ([`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and [`org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't do like that . Get the date Using `Date` Object and parse it Using `SimpleDateFormat` . its Simple . Don't Go For Hard Coding the value. its Not Convenient  for programmer   . please find Code

```
Date date  = new Date();//Today Date
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");// FOrmat in This Format or you change Change as well 
String Format= format.format(date);
System.out.println(Format);// 01/06/2016
```

or

```
Calendar TodayDate = Calendar.getInstance();
TodayDate.add(Calendar.DAY_ON_MONTH, -1);//import java.util.*
Date yesterday = cal.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String Format = format.format(yesterday);
System.out.println(Format);// 01/06/2016
```

Comment: No need to write `"" +` in the calls to `println`.  You mean `DAY_OF_MONTH`.  And almost everyone in the world uses lower case for the first letter of a variable name, and your code will therefore be more universally readable if you do the same.

Comment: but here we get the formatted output as String, how to get the format("MM/dd/yyyy") as date type itself.

Answer (score 1):

To get yesterdays date and format it, you have 3 choices:

```java
// Use Java 8+ LocalDate
java.time.LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);

String text = yesterday.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu"));
```

```java
// Use Joda-Time (3rd-party library)
org.joda.time.LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);

String text = yesterday.toString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

```java
// Use Calendar (all Java versions, no 3rd-party library)
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_ON_MONTH, -1);
java.util.Date yesterday = cal.getTime();

String text = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(yesterday);
```

Note that `Calendar` version still produces a "date" value with time-of-day. Extra code would be needed to clear the time fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String DateToStr = format.format(yesterdaydate);
out.println(DateToStr);
```

Comment: @Buwaneka Sumanasekara - your example is perfectly self-explanatory ... and, as far as I can see, correct.  +1.  It's still worth pointing out that the OP's "date diff" method is *WRONG*.  I'd recommend the new Java 8 date/time functions, Joda time, or - as the others pointed out - Calendar.add().