# Java LocalDate check if 18 years old and above

Tags: java, date

I have 2 localdate, one is birthdate and one is date today.
What is the fastest way to compare them and check if the age is 18 years old and above? Do I need to convert this to string and split them then compare them 1 by 1? Or is there another way of comparing this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

Answer (score 9):

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later has classes with lots of methods to solve the issue. The best one is finding [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html). The exact code will be,

```
period = Period.between(start, end);
```

Here the `start` will be your birthday such as [`LocalDate.of( 1955 , 1 , 2 )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#of-int-int-int-) and `end` will be today: [`LocalDate.now()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-).

After that you can get `period.getYears()` which returns an `int` value. Its easy to check condition that you want.

See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Reference: [Java 8: Calculate difference between two LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime),
[LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1960, Month.JANUARY, 1);

Period p = Period.between(birthday, today);
long p2 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(birthday, today);
System.out.println("You are " + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() +
               " months, and " + p.getDays() +
               " days old. (" + p2 + " days total)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wery way of doing it

```
long age = LocalDate.from(birthday)).until(LocalDate.now(), ChronoUnit.YEARS);
```