# Java Subtracting LocalDateTime foo from LocalDateTime Bar

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, casting

I know this is probably a really stupid question, however I was wondering whether there is a way to minus a local date time from another, or if not, to cast localDateTime to just Date time and then subtract from there?

I need to be able to work out the date time difference, between the start of record foo and the start of record bar (which is also the end of Foo)

I am rather new to java, and for simplicity's sake, I want to be able to keep it in roughly the same layout, rather than having to convert from seconds etc.

If adding and subtracting LocalDateTime is not an option, I know that once I am in dateTime I am able to subtract them using:

```
Period diff = new Period(start, end);
```

Due to the purpose of the data, I need to keep both the date and the time in order for this to work, and as mentioned before, I wish to keep it fairly simple so theres no need to convert between seconds back to the date.

My issue is really just getting it in an acceptable format, as I say, I am rather new to java and object orientation as a whole, so please don't ridicule me for this, seemingly simple, question.

Thanks,

Jonny

Comment: Answered already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime

Comment: If you meant this Question to refer to Joda-Time classes, then you should say so explicitly. Also, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode and advised migration to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you not simply use directly `LocalDateTime` as parameter type this way:

```
LocalDateTime start = new LocalDateTime(2016, 10, 4, 17, 45);
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.now();
PeriodType ptype = PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime();
Period diff = new Period(start, end, ptype);
```

See also the [API of Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period-org.joda.time.ReadablePartial-org.joda.time.ReadablePartial-org.joda.time.PeriodType-). You don't need to cast to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 48):

*The question is about Joda-Time, not about Java 8. The question wasn't really clear about it. Anyways, this answer is about Java 8 and therefore doesn't directly answers the question. Though I think it's an appropriate answer if anyone wants to use Java 8 instead.*

You should probably check the [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
LocalDateTime from = ... ;
LocalDateTime to = ... ;
Duration duration = Duration.between(from, to);
```

If you really want to obtain a `Period`, it's still rather easy:

```
LocalDateTime from = ... ;
LocalDateTime to = ... ;
Period period = Period.between(from.toLocalDate(), to.toLocalDate());
```

Comment: The OP obviously uses Joda-Time, not Java-8-time-api, see the usage of Period-constructor..

Comment: Thanks, however it keeps returning POD, is this caused by the same date, as this is only toLocalDate, as opposed to the time included?

Comment: @Jonnyr612 In contrast to Joda-Time or other APIs, Java-8 (java.time-package) does NOT manage durations consisting of date and time units together.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Obviously? No. Several class names are the same, no `joda-time` tag but after more scrutiny, you are right, the question is not about Java 8.