# Convert Days to years months and weeks in java?

Tags: java

Basically I've:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

String ActualDate          = "2017-01-05";
LocalDate dt               = LocalDate.parse(ActualDate, formatter);
LocalDateTime currentdate  = LocalDateTime.now();
String datetocheckstr      = currentdate.toString().substring(0, 10);
LocalDate datetochkbetween = LocalDate.parse(datetocheckstr, formatter);
long DAYS                  = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(datetochkbetween, dt);
```

This pretty much works and show you the amount of days between the `ActualDate` and `now`.

Now I need to convert it to Years, Months, And days.
So if My `ActualDate = "2015-02-15"` and Now It's `2017-03-27` the output I need to get is to be:  `2 Years 1 Month and 12 Days`.

Peace be upon us all

Answer (score 4):

You can use Period class from java 8.
I have updated your code. 
Try it:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String ActualDate = "2015-02-15";
    LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(ActualDate, formatter);
    LocalDate currentdate = LocalDate.now();
    Period period = Period.between(dt, currentdate);
    System.out.println("Years " + period.getYears());  //Years 2
    System.out.println("Months " + period.getMonths()); //Months 1
    System.out.println("Days " + period.getDays()); //Days 11
```

Comment: Thank you so much worked perfect, can you also tell how to do the same thing with `LocalTime`? I'm currently doing it this way `long duration = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(now, timetotime);`

Comment: You might check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime

Comment: Thanks man, this works perfectly and saved me a lot of time!