# Calculate date range until future date

Tags: java

I want to calculate interval until some date. I tested this code:

```
 String dateStop = "25/11/17 09:00:00";

        // Custom date format
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

        LocalDateTime d1 = LocalDateTime.now();
        Date d2 = null;
        try
        {
            d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get msec from each, and subtract.
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diff);
        long remainingHoursInMillis = diff - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
        long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(remainingHoursInMillis);
        long remainingMinutesInMillis = remainingHoursInMillis - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(remainingMinutesInMillis);
        long remainingSecondsInMillis = remainingMinutesInMillis - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(remainingSecondsInMillis);

        System.out.println("Days: " + days + ", hours: " + hours + ", minutes: " + minutes + ", seconds: " + seconds);
```

But How I can get current date and calculate the time difference? I get exception here:   location: variable d1 of type LocalDateTime

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: ***what*** exception are you receiving?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-calculate-difference-between-two-localdatetime

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getTime()` for `LocalDateTime`. Use the `Date` class for `d1` instead or convert to it:

```
java.util.Date.from( d1.toInstant() ).getTime();
```

Comment: Ok, for Date how I can get current date?

Comment: I edited the answer to show you how to get the current time with your current `LocalDateTime d1`

Comment: I would *strongly* avoid using `java.util.Date`. Definitely prefer java.time instead. Note that from an `Instant`, you can just call `toEpochMilli()`.