# Calculating number of months between two OffsetDateTimes

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, date-difference

I am using java 8 and I'm trying to calculate the amount of months between two OffsetDateTime objects. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what is your sample input + expected output data?

Comment: How hard did you search? Might you for example have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26954864/5772882)?

Answer (score 15):

Without more details, the standard way would be:

```
long months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(odt1, odt2);
```

Answer (score 5):

the most comprehensible way (IMO) is to use [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html)

```
        OffsetDateTime odt1 = OffsetDateTime.now();
        OffsetDateTime odt2 = odt1.plusMonths(10);
        System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(odt1, odt2));
```

Comment: If it works you can mark an answer as solution ;)