# Count runtime Java

Tags: java, time, count, runtime

This is a college job.

Java language / I use Eclipse IDE

I need to count the running time of my program.

I want to print the runtime.

Example:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

...
LocalDateTime start;
LocalDateTime end;

start = LocalDateTime.now();

...
xx my code xxx
...

end = LocalDateTime.now();

<<here I have doubts
```

I need to calculate "end - start" and pass the result to String

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8: Difference between two LocalDateTime in multiple units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-difference-between-two-localdatetime-in-multiple-units)

Comment: @Eritrean Not really a duplicate of that specific Question. Given the context presented here, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to accomplish this person’s goal. Thus, [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486393/642706).

Comment: [Measure Elapsed Time in Java | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-measure-elapsed-time). [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java) I downvoted because it seems you forgot to search prior to posting your question(?)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Duration              // Represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds. 
.between(             // Calculate time elapsed between two `Instant` objects. 
    then ,            // An `Instant` object instantiated earlier.
    Instant.now()     // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). 
)                     // Returns a `Duration` object.
.toString()           // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

## `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment

[`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is the wrong class for tracking specific points on the timeline. That class purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot represent a moment. I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do.

For example, if you were to calculate elapsed time during which a [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cut-over occurred, your result would be incorrect. The `LocalDateTime` class ignores any offset changes in that time zone.

## Track elapsed time with `java.time.Instant`

Instead, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
…
Instant end = Instant.now() ;
```

### Represent elapsed time with `java.time.Duration`

Calculate elapsed time using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , end ) ;
```

Generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). Example: `PT30M` for exactly one half-hour.

```
String output = elapsed.toString() ;
```

To generate text in other formats, access the parts by calling `to…Part` methods.