# Java - Collectors.groupingBy - the last 15 days

Tags: java, collectors

is it possible to group by the last 15 days using Java's `Collectors.groupingBy`?

**Input:**

```
public class Tweet { 

 String id;
 LocalDate createdAt; 

 // Constructor Ignored

 List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList(){{
  add(new Tweet("1", "2021-11-17"));
  add(new Tweet("2", "2021-11-16"));
  add(new Tweet("3", "2021-11-14"));
  add(new Tweet("4", "2021-11-13"));
  add(new Tweet("5", "2021-11-12"));
  add(new Tweet("7", "2021-10-09"));
  add(new Tweet("8", "2021-10-08"));
  add(new Tweet("9", "2021-10-07"));
  add(new Tweet("10", "2021-09-02"));
  add(new Tweet("11", "2021-09-01"));
 ...

 }};

}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2021-11-17:  (group must include 2021-11-17 + 15 days before 17th)
 Tweet("1", "2021-11-17");
 Tweet("2", "2021-11-16");
 Tweet("3", "2021-11-14");
 Tweet("4", "2021-11-13");
 Tweet("5", "2021-11-12");

2021-10-09: (group to include 2021-10-09 + 15 days before 9th)
 Tweet("7", "2021-10-09");
 Tweet("8", "2021-10-08");
 Tweet("9", "2021-10-07");

2021-09-01: (group to include 2021-09-01 + 15 days before 1st)
Tweet("10", "2021-09-02");
Tweet("11", "2021-09-01");
```

Current logic (**Not working**):

**Main Method:**

```java
TemporalAdjusters adjuster = TemporalAdjusters.ofDateAdjuster(d -> d.minusDays(15));

Map<LocalDate, List<Tweets>> groupByLast15Days = tweets.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.createdAt())
                  .with(adjuster)));

System.out.println(groupByLast15Days);  // provides incorrect results
```

any help is massively appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: why not use `.filter(...)` instead?

Comment: @blurfus - I don't think `filter()` alone can do the trick.  `Collectors.GroupBy` seems more elegant.

Comment: Are you trying to group into buckets of length 15 days?  Or filter out entries more than 15 days ago?

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I am trying to group them into buckets of the length of 15 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the day difference between two `LocalDateTime`s using `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from,to)` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26954864/10871900).

You can then divide this by 15 (so you have the same number for all days in that range):

```java
LocalDate origin=LocalDate.now();
Map<LocalDate, List<Tweets>> groupByLast15Days = tweets.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item-> 
       Long.valueOf(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(item.createdAt(),origin)/15));
```

If you want to group by the start date, you can reverse the calculation (while the difference in between the 15 days is eliminated by the integer division):

```java
LocalDate origin=LocalDate.now();
Map<LocalDate, List<Tweets>> groupByLast15Days = tweets.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> 
        origin.plusDays(
            (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(origin, item.createdAt()) /15)*15
        )
    ));
```

If you want to use `TemporalAdjusters`, you can do it like that:

```java
LocalDate origin=LocalDate.now();
TemporalAdjusters adjuster = TemporalAdjusters.ofDateAdjuster(d ->
    origin.plusDays(
        (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(origin, d) /15)*15
    )
);
```

---

**Explainations**:

Dividing an integer by another integer always yields an integer, even if the quotient would have decimal places. Integer division just removes those decimal places. If you divide a number by 15, it will return rhe same result for 15 consecutive numbers. After multiplying it with 15 again, you would get the first of those 15 numbers. Dividing a number by 15 and multiplying it with 15 again has the purpose that every 15 consecutive numbers are set to the same number (the first of those 15).

`ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2)` just calculates the number of days between `date1` and `date2`.

Comment: Wow that was fast.. Is it possible to have the origin as `item.createdAt()` instead of `now()`? I want to group them by `item.createAt() - 15`. The `creationAt` date may not be today's date..

Comment: `origin` can be any date but it needs to be the same date for all elements.

Comment: The only difference is when each set of 15 days starts (shifting `origin` by one day means each block will start one day later, shifting it by 15 days does nothing)

Comment: let me try it out.. is there a syntax error?  getting compilation error at the line `item.createdAt()/15` in solution 2. - `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(origin, item.createdAt()/15)`

Comment: I fixed it. See my edit.

Comment: Solution 2 and 3 works like a charm! Are you able to explain how ChronoUnit works and why are we multiplying 15 and then dividing by 15? Say if I want to change the 15 days interval to 10. Do I simply change them both to 10?

Comment: I edited my answer. Yes, changing both to 10 would merge every 10 consecutive days.