# How to get the hours with minutes between two LocalTime times

Tags: java

Right now, I can get the hours between two LocalTime times like this:

```
public long getHours(){
        return ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(this.timeIn, this.timeOut);
    }
```

But the result is only the number of hours. What I want is to also include the minutes as well. So for example if 5 hours and 30 minutes passed the result to be 5.30.

EDIT:
For example timeIn is 10:00:00 and time out is 15:30:00. I want the hours and minutes between these two times

Comment: can you add the value of this.timeIn, this.timeOut?

Comment: sure timeIn it's just LocalTime.now and timeOut is LocalTime.of so we can say that time in is 10:00:00 and time out is 15:30:00

Comment: public long getHours(){
        return ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(this.timeIn, this.timeOut) / 60;
    }
won't do the trick?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747499/java-8-difference-between-two-localdatetime-in-multiple-units

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Duration.between` method from the java.time API:

```
public static Duration getDuration(){
    LocalTime timeIn  = LocalTime.now();;
    LocalTime timeOut = timeIn.plusHours(5).plusMinutes(30).plusSeconds(23);
    return Duration.between(timeIn, timeOut);
}
```

Returned for above example:

```
PT5H30M23S
```

That text is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

To format it differently use the methods `toXXXPart()` from the `Duration` class:

```
public static String format(Duration duration) {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
}
```

A sample output with the same above example:

```
System.out.println(format(getDuration()));
```

prints

```
05:30:23
```