# how to convert date to seconds in java

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a date column in `postgres db` whose value is `2018-11-20 22:07:20`. The datatype is `timestamz`. I want to get the above value in java code and convert that to seconds with respect to the current time. Suppose the current date is `2018-11-21 22:07:20` then the final answer should be 86400 seconds. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far? You should attempt the problem before asking for a solution.

Comment: "2018-11-21 22:07:20" is a string ? wich version of java do you use?

Comment: Do both dates come from the same locale? Did the locale's time zone, or time zone rules change in between the two dates? Was there a leap day, leap second, or a daylight savings turnover in between the two dates? Time diffs are harder than some people will try to tell you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I get the difference in seconds between 2 dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970239/in-java-how-do-i-get-the-difference-in-seconds-between-2-dates)

Comment: I assume you mean `timestamp without time zone` (which is a pity if true because then you’ve got an ambiguous point in time). According to [PostgrSQL JDBC Driver documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/java8-date-time.html) you can get a `LocalDateTime` from JDBC, which will come handy into a couple of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Duration                                                // Represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline.
.between(                                               // Calculate elapsed time between two moments.
    OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ,              // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
    myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class )   // Retrieve the moment stored in your database as a `OffsetDateTime` object, *not* as a mere string.
)                                                       // Return a `Duration` object.
.toSeconds()                                            // View that duration as a total number of whole seconds. Obviously, any fractional second is ignored.
```

## Details

The [Answer by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53397900/642706) is close but not quite correct.

- It fails to account for anomalies in your local time zone, such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time): `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class there, as it cannot, by definition, represent a moment.
- It also fails to address the bigger problem that dumb strings are being used to exchange date-time values with the database rather than using smart objects.

> date column in postgres db whose value is 2018-11-20 22:07:20

No, that is not the value of the column. That is a textual representation of the value. What is the distinction? Well, unfortunately, many tools used to access your data take the liberty of altering the data being retrieved by applying a time zone adjustment.

Even worse, your example text lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. This contradicts your next statement.

> The datatype is timestamz.

I think you misspelled `timestampz` (missing the `p`). Even so, this seems to be incorrect, as no such type is listed among the [Postgres date/time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). Some systems use that word as an abbreviation, but I recommend always using the longer SQL-standard name for clarity.

You likely meant the type [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) which Postgres, like some other databases, stores as a value in UTC. Any indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) present within incoming data is used to adjust to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), then the indicator is discarded. So values going into, and out of, **a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column in Postgres is *always* in UTC**. Beware, as mentioned above, some tools interfere with the data retrieval by injecting a time zone adjustment, a well-intentioned though very confusing anti-feature.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database via `setObject` and `getObject` methods. Use the object rather than mere strings to exchange date-time values.

## `OffsetDateTime`

Retrieve your value from a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as an `OffsetDateTime` value with its offset set to UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odtThen = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

For comparison, get the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Specify the offset using the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odtNow = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

To generate text representing that duration in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) format, call `OffsetDateTime::toString`.

## `Duration`

Capture elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( odtNow , odtThen ) ;
```

To generate text representing that duration in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format, call `Duration::toString`.

```
String output = d.toString() ;  // PnYnMnDTnHnMnS
```

To see that entire duration as one big count of whole seconds, call [`Duration::toSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toSeconds()).

```
long secondsElapsed = d.toSeconds() ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

By the way, if you wish to view either the that `odtThen` or `odtNow` value through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odtThen.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Parse into a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), then get the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) between that and the current time, and [convert it to seconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#getSeconds--).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("your pattern");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-11-20 22:07:20", formatter);
return Duration.between(dateTime, LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds();
```

You can work out the pattern yourself.

Comment: This assumes that the record in the database is from the same time zone that OP's code is going to be running in.

Comment: Nice answer. I recommend you specify time zone explicitly (even if you just specify `ZoneId.systemDefault()`).

Comment: @mypetlion When neither has a timezone, that is only sensible assumption that one can make.

Comment: Agreed. But I do think it worth noting to OP and future readers what assumptions are being made. If OP has control over what gets recorded in the database, it should be recommended to them that they additionally record the time zone, going forward.

Comment: Thanks, @mypetlion, for at least making the assumption clear and explicit. I agree that this will help readers now and in the future (another sensible assumption might be that the date-time from PostgreSQL is in UTC; that would at least be good practice; but it’s still only a fragile assumption).

Comment: **Incorrect.** While not defined in Postgres, the `TIMESTAMPTZ` mentioned in the Question in other databases represents a moment, meaning a date+time in a particular time zone or offset-from-UTC. In Postgres, that would mean a column of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type. So, the code shown in this Answer uses the wrong class, `LocalDateTime`. By definition, that class cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. So this code fails to account for anomalies seen in various time zones on various dates, such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutover.